# Adding ID attribute to appended element

Tags: jquery

I'm adding a new tag to an element with ID XX:

```
$("#XX").append("<div>");
```

I want the inner div to have an id set too. Is there a more elegant way using jquery function than the following:

```
$("#XX").append("<div id=\""+"testID"+"\">");
```

I tried to do a:

```
 $("#XX").append("<div>").attr()
```

however this changed the id of XX.

Comment: You could do (or any variation of ) `$("#XX").append("<div>").children().last().attr('id', testID)`, but i wouldn't consider that to be any more elegant than simply using string concatenation.

Comment: Whoever voted down my post can you please why?

Comment: To the #ucking arsehole that downvoted this comment. I don't mind but have the balls to make a comment first and tell me why.

Comment: Kevin if you voted down my question. Did you not think this was a worthy question?

Comment: I didn't think it was that useful, and didn't particularly like that it was worded as a "What's a *better* way of doing this?" without explaining what you would consider to be more elegant. performance-wise the string concatenation will win, and i find it to no harder to maintain/read than the alternatives, at least with your example. If it got more advanced, a templating engine would do better.

Comment: Ha! why not simply ask the question to clarify then? I didn't particularly like your alternate solution either; in fact the one below is much more _elegant_. Perhaps that will give you some material to go away an analyse elegant code... (I.e. readable and less code).

Comment: <on introspection I have removed my comment because it was inappropriate> Ok thanks for your advice Kevin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#xx').append(
    $('<div />').attr('id', 'test_id')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for that so you would then set the content of the div with another line I'm assuming?

Comment: Yeah, you can chain another command after `.attr` or you can roll up the whole thing into one command:

    `$('<div />', {id: 'test_id', /* some other HTML attribute */})`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("#XX").append( $("<div \>").attr("id","myID") );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$('#xx').append('<div id="test_id"></div>');
```

Comment: what's wrong in this? I'm asking to the person had marked it as negative

Comment: I didn't vote this answer down, but I can tell you two ways to improve.
(1) Use some punctuation. "try this one" looks like spam email, so next time write, "Here's one solution; here's why it works."
(2) Your answer wasn't as good as yaycmyk's. Maybe someone thought you should be voted down for that reason; seems inappropriate to me. You're going to see that a lot on SO: people with better answers than yours. It's important that you continue to participate, so that your Q&A skills improve, and so your best answers help people out.

Answer (score 0):

You may like this option better:

```js
var testId = 'foo';
$('<div>', {
  id: testId
}).appendTo('#XX');

$("#foo").html('Worky!');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="XX"></div>
```

You can of course add other attributes, or even event handlers and html to that object.

```js
var testId = 'foo';
$('<div>', {
  id: testId,
  click: function () {
    $(this).html('Hello World!');
  },
  html: 'Click Me'
}).appendTo('#XX');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="XX"></div>
```

[Further Reading](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

Comment: I usually stay away from generating elements in this way and instead use string concatenation (or templating) due to how complex this becomes once you start generating nested structures of elements.